# Javascript cookies not creating

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Hi guys I'm trying to create cookies but with no success. Here is my site code I cant figure out why I cant get the cookie I created?

Edit site's full code added

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>yensdesign.com - How to create a stuning and smooth popup in jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="general.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setCookie(name,value,days)
        {
            var date=new Date();
            var exdays = days*24*60*60*1000;
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value=escape(value) + ((days==null) ? "" : "; expires="+date.toUTCString());
            document.cookie=name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        function getCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }

        function deleteCookie(name) {
            setCookie(name,"",-1);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setCookie('myCookie', 'myValue', 1);">
    <center>
        <a href="http://www.yensdesign.com"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="Go to yensdesign.com"/></a>
        <div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Press me please!" /></div>
        <div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Cookie!" onclick=getCookie('myCookie'); /></div>
    </center>
    <div id="popupContact"></div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the cookie creation that seems not working:

```
<body onload="setCookie('myCookie', 'myValue', 1);">
```

so what can be the problem here?

Comment: Are you serving this page from a web server, or locally from a file:/// url? Your comment to @jmoresca makes me think that you might be trying to do this from your local filesystem. Cookies don't work that way; you need a server -- even if it's running locally -- for them to function at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that **cookies do not work locally with Chrome**! Tried with Firefox and worked well. If you want to see it in action you have to upload your files to a server or localhost and view see how it works in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
       function setCookie(name,value,days) {
            if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
            else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
        }

        function getCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }

        function deleteCookie(name) {
            setCookie(name,"",-1);
        }

        function clickMe() {
           alert(getCookie('myCookie'));
        }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="setCookie('myCookie', 'myValue', 1);">
<input type="button" onClick="clickMe()" value="test" />
</html>
```

Comment: returns null! Should I run this code on a server or I can do it locally

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
function setCookie(name,value,days)
{
var date=new Date();
var exdays = days*24*60*60*1000;
date.setDate(date.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((days==null) ? "" : "; expires="+date.toUTCString());
document.cookie=name + "=" + c_value;
}    

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(';');
 for (i=0; i < ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf('='));
y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
if (x==c_name)
{
return unescape(y);
}
}
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
        setCookie(name,"",-1);
    }

    function clickMe() {
       alert(getCookie('myCookie'));
    }
```

[check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/cqQtU/1/)

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Chauchan still doesn't run...I've updated my question with the full code